# Need help creating a loop where you feed column names into transmute() after group_by()

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, merge, binary-data

I currently have a data frame `df` where the first column is self-identified races (factor) and the remaining columns are all symptoms (numeric) with binary values (0 = absent, 1 = present). Each row represents a patient (other demographic information has been cleared from the data frame prior to this step). Random example:

| Race (factor) | Headache (num) | Paraesthesias (num) | Heartburn (num) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| White | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| Asian | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| White | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| Asian | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Black | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Asian | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| Black | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| White | 1 | 0 | 1 |

My goal is to create one data frame where the first column is the 3 unique race factors and each symptom column has the percentage of individuals of that race who have the symptom. Such as this:

| Race (factor) | Headache | Paraesthesias | Heartburn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| White | 0.666 | 0.333 | 0.666 |
| Asian | 0.333 | 0.666 | 0.666 |
| Black | 0.5 | 0.5 | 0.5 |

This code works great for creating a data frame for one column

```
unique(df %>% group_by(race) %>% drop_na %>% transmute(Headache = sum(Headache)/length(race)) %>% ungroup)
```

and I will end up with a data frame such as

| Race (factor) | Headache |
| --- | --- |
| White | 0.6666 |
| Asian | 0.3333 |
| Black | 0.5 |

I could manually repeat this process and merge the resultant data frames, but my actual data frame has 60+ symptoms so this would be quite tedious and ugly.

I figured there was a loop that I could create for this.

**This step is where I've been having difficulty.**

I have tried

```
y <- tibble
for (i in colnames(df)[-1]) {
    z <- unique(df %>% group_by(race) %>% 
drop_na %>% transmute(i = sum(i)/length(race)) %>% ungroup)
    y <- merge(y, z)
}
```

and get

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `i`.
ℹ `i = sum(i)/length(race)`.
x invalid 'type' (character) of argument
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: race = Asian.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I then tried

```
y <- tibble
for (i in 2:4) {
    z <- unique(df %>% group_by(race) %>% 
drop_na %>% mutate_at(colnames(bp1[i])) = sum(colnames(bp1[i]))/length(race)) %>% ungroup)
    y <- merge(y, z)
}
```

which produces

```
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"        z <- unique(df %>% group_by(race) %>% 
drop_na %>% mutate_at(get(colnames(df[i])) ="
>   y <- merge(y, z)
Error in as.data.frame.default(x) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"function"’ to a data.frame
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

I presume the reason these errors are occurring is that when I am calling the column name it is producing it as a character and not an object for the transmute function to work with (or something like this? I am very new to R so not sure about the correct terminology). I assume this would apply across all dplyr packages.

Is there a way around this? I am happy to go a couple steps back if it is suggested, e.g., if my original data frame should be changed to make this step easier.

P.S. As a side note if anyone has advice on how to create a fourth row under race named "Total" with subsequently the total prevalences across rate in the symptom columns that would also be useful!

Such as this:

| Race (factor) | Headache | Paraesthesias | Heartburn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| White | 0.666 | 0.333 | 0.666 |
| Asian | 0.333 | 0.666 | 0.666 |
| Black | 0.5 | 0.5 | 0.5 |
| Total | 0.5 | 0.5 | 0.625 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have binary values in the data one way to simplify this would be to take average of them for each unique `Race`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Race) %>% summarise(across(.fns = mean, na.rm = TRUE))

#  Race  Headache Paraesthesias Heartburn
#  <chr>    <dbl>         <dbl>     <dbl>
#1 Asian    0.333         0.667     0.667
#2 Black    0.5           0.5       0.5  
#3 White    0.667         0.333     0.667
```

In base R, you can use -

```
aggregate(.~Race, df, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

**data**

It is easier to help if share data in a reproducible format.

```
df <- structure(list(Race = c("White", "Asian", "White", "Asian", "Black", 
"Asian", "Black", "White"), Headache = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L), Paraesthesias = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L
), Heartburn = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: wow awesome! such simple code too. I had never seen across() or .fns before. What do these mean in this context? Also one issue that I have is that there are NA values in various columns so I want to use drop_na but I don't want to drop the row for each column summary (because a patient may have a NA value for one symptom but not another) and noted re: sharing data in the future in a reproducible format.

Comment: When you have binary data like `x <- c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0)` to take proportion a shortcut is to just take mean of it. `mean(x)`. This is same as `sum(x)/length(x)`. I added `na.rm = TRUE` to ignore the `NA` values in the data.

Comment: You could add `%>%
  bind_rows(df %>%  summarize(across(-Race, .fns = mean, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% mutate(Race = "Total"))` to this chain to get the total row.

Comment: thank you both! were the data not binary - and I were to require to insert column names to example create a loop producing contingency table, how would I do this? For example ```df %>% drop_na %>% tabyl(race, symptom col name)```

Comment: It would be better if you ask that as a new question showing appropriate non-binary data with expected output as you have shown in this question.

Comment: Just created one, thanks for all your help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68784753/for-loop-utilizing-colnames-as-object-in-tabyl-pipeline

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm = TRUE), by = Race]
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Race = c("White", "Asian", "White", "Asian", "Black", 
"Asian", "Black", "White"), Headache = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L), Paraesthesias = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L
), Heartburn = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = "data.frame")
```